# Require user to input code from an array of allowed codes with Gravity Forms

Tags: validation, plugin-gravity-forms

I have a gravity form that I want to, only allow people submit if they enter a specific code from a possible list of 3.

**Example codes**

1. XH6D
2. 8U2A
3. L9D3

If a user enters **XH6D** into the form, the form will successfully submit, otherwise the form will return an error.

Easy to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code:

```
add_filter( 'gform_field_validation', 'custom_validation', 10, 4 );
function custom_validation( $result, $value, $form, $field ) {
    $arrWhitelist = array('XH6D', '8U2A', 'L9D3');
    if ( $result['is_valid'] && !in_array( $value, $arrWhitelist )) {
        $result['is_valid'] = false;
        $result['message'] = 'Please enter a value less than 10';
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Further, You can review validation in more detail from [this](https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/gform_field_validation/#4-name-field-validation) url